# Why does Puma create multiple PIDs if its multi-thread instead of multi-process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, puma

Why does Puma create multiple PIDs if its multi-threaded?

I thought the multiple threads would exist inside the same process.

When starting Puma locally:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[22095] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[22095] * Version 3.6.0 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Sleepy Sunday Serenity
[22095] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 1
[22095] * Environment: development
[22095] * Process workers: 2
[22095] * Preloading application
[22095] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[22095] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[22095] - Worker 0 (pid: 22183) booted, phase: 0
[22095] - Worker 1 (pid: 22184) booted, phase: 0
```

When running `ps aux | grep puma`:

```
me  22184  ... puma: cluster worker 1: 22095 [app]    
me  22183  ... puma:  cluster worker 0: 22095 [app] 
me  22095  ... puma 3.6.0 (tcp://localhost:3000) [app]   
me  22289  ... grep puma
```

I've been learning about threads vs processes, and I thought that a thread is a "path of execution inside a process", so this struck me as confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puma is a threaded server but also allows multiple workers (processes). If you look at the initialization logs it mentions how many `workers` it spawned.

```
[22095] * Process workers: 2
```

This is called Puma's clustered mode. Each process will spawn

```
[22095] * Min threads: 1, max threads: 1
```

amount of threads to handle requests concurrently.

Read more about it: [Puma Clustered Mode](https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode)